# Give the numbers to all month which are as string in my database, and next row to be autofill when user select any month

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I want to make this **"month_no"** field autofill, when the user sends or inserts data in the previous field which **for_month** as the month in string format I want month_no to be filed automatically.
This is my table named `tbl_transactions` with columns in SQL Server.

```
Category (string)
for_month (string)
month_no (int) *<--new column, I want this to be autofilled when the user selects the data in the previous row*
Vehicle_No (string)
amount (float)
```

as shown below in the screenshot.

[image]

Is it possible to achieve?

Thanks.

I've tried with the below code to achieve the result. below code works well with one entry but not with multiple entries as mentioned below. Moreover, I want this field to be autofill.

```
    DECLARE @jan int = 1
    DECLARE @feb int = 2
    DECLARE @mar int = 3
    DECLARE @apr int = 4
    DECLARE @may int = 5
    DECLARE @jun int = 6
    DECLARE @jul int = 7
    DECLARE @aug int = 8
    DECLARE @sep int = 9
    DECLARE @oct int = 10
    DECLARE @nov int = 11
    DECLARE @dec int = 12

    UPDATE tbl_transactions
    SET month_no = @jan where for_month = 'JANUARY';
    SET month_no = @feb where for_month = 'FEBURARY';
    SET month_no = @mar where for_month = 'MARCH';
    SET month_no = @apr where for_month = 'APRIL';
    SET month_no = @may where for_month = 'MAY';
    SET month_no = @jun where for_month = 'JUNE';
    SET month_no = @jul where for_month = 'JULY';
    SET month_no = @aug where for_month = 'AUGUST';
    SET month_no = @sep where for_month = 'SEPTEMBER';
    SET month_no = @oct where for_month = 'OCTOBER';
    SET month_no = @nov where for_month = 'NOVEMBER';
    SET month_no = @dec where for_month = 'DECEMBER';
```

The insert html code is as follows

```
<div class="forMonthOf">
 <label for="forMonthOf" class="label-forMonthOf">
   <p>For the Month</p>
   <input id="forMonthOf" name="forMonthOf" type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
 </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Your screen has escaped the shot.

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off storing the month number, and then converting it to a string when you query it? Rather than storing it twice? Even if you don't swap them around, you shouldn't store it, you should calculate it when you run a query.

Comment: @DaleK, Thanks for your reply. Noted your suggestions. I've actually tried to achieve the required result using variable but unable to achieve the same.

Comment: Autofill implies an insert, so show us the insert you are using.

Comment: And for autofill, do you want to calculate it as part of the insert statement? Or do you want a trigger to automatically update it regardless of how the insert happens?

Comment: Yes, I want it to trigger automatically regardless of how insert happens because it is not related to the end-user to input, it just for the backend process to flow smoothly.

Comment: In that case I suggest your check out the documentation [create trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and then ask a new, specific question, should you get stuck. BTW we're not that interested in the HTML, its the SQL insert thats of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simple `CASE` statement in your `SELECT`? You can run the following in SSMS.

```
/* MOCK-UP SRUCTURE AND DATA */

DECLARE @tbl_transactions table (
    category varchar(50), for_month varchar(15), vehicle_no varchar(50), amount decimal(18,2)
);

INSERT INTO @tbl_transactions VALUES
    ( 'Registration', 'April', 123, 350 ),
    ( 'Registration', 'April', 456, 450 ),
    ( 'Registration', 'April', 739, 295 ),
    ( 'Maintenance', 'April', 123, 1500 ),
    ( 'Maintenance', 'April', 456, 1050 ),
    ( 'Maintenance', 'April', 789, 650 ),
    ( 'Fuel', 'April', 123, 2009 ),
    ( 'Fuel', 'April', 456, 1520 ),
    ( 'Fuel', 'April', 789, 1675 ),
    ( 'Registration', 'May', 123, 250 ),
    ( 'Registration', 'May', 456, 375 ),
    ( 'Registration', 'May', 789, 460 ),
    ( 'Maintenance', 'May', 123, 1200 ),
    ( 'Maintenance', 'May', 456, 950 ),
    ( 'Maintenance', 'May', 789, 750 ),
    ( 'Fuel', 'May', 123, 1225 ),
    ( 'Fuel', 'May', 456, 1000 ),
    ( 'Fuel', 'May', 789, 1650 ),
    ( 'Registration', 'June', 123, 325 ),
    ( 'Registration', 'June', 456, 428 ),
    ( 'Registration', 'June', 789, 165 ),
    ( 'Maintenance', 'June', 123, 1850 ),
    ( 'Maintenance', 'June', 456, 2509 ),
    ( 'Maintenance', 'June', 789, 1600 ),
    ( 'Fuel', 'June', 123, 1225 ),
    ( 'Fuel', 'June', 456, 1055 ),
    ( 'Fuel', 'June', 789, 275 );

/* Select data and determine the month number by month name */

SELECT
    category,
    for_month,
    CASE LOWER( LEFT ( for_month, 3 ) )
        WHEN 'jan' THEN 1
        WHEN 'feb' THEN 2
        WHEN 'mar' THEN 3
        WHEN 'apr' THEN 4
        WHEN 'may' THEN 5
        WHEN 'jun' THEN 6
        WHEN 'jul' THEN 7
        WHEN 'aug' THEN 8
        WHEN 'sep' THEN 9
        WHEN 'oct' THEN 10
        WHEN 'nov' THEN 11
        WHEN 'dec' THEN 12
        ELSE 0
    END AS month_no,
    vehicle_no,
    amount
FROM @tbl_transactions;
```

Returns

```
+--------------+-----------+----------+------------+---------+
|   category   | for_month | month_no | vehicle_no | amount  |
+--------------+-----------+----------+------------+---------+
| Registration | April     |        4 |        123 | 350.00  |
| Registration | April     |        4 |        456 | 450.00  |
| Registration | April     |        4 |        739 | 295.00  |
| Maintenance  | April     |        4 |        123 | 1500.00 |
| Maintenance  | April     |        4 |        456 | 1050.00 |
| Maintenance  | April     |        4 |        789 | 650.00  |
| Fuel         | April     |        4 |        123 | 2009.00 |
| Fuel         | April     |        4 |        456 | 1520.00 |
| Fuel         | April     |        4 |        789 | 1675.00 |
| Registration | May       |        5 |        123 | 250.00  |
| Registration | May       |        5 |        456 | 375.00  |
| Registration | May       |        5 |        789 | 460.00  |
| Maintenance  | May       |        5 |        123 | 1200.00 |
| Maintenance  | May       |        5 |        456 | 950.00  |
| Maintenance  | May       |        5 |        789 | 750.00  |
| Fuel         | May       |        5 |        123 | 1225.00 |
| Fuel         | May       |        5 |        456 | 1000.00 |
| Fuel         | May       |        5 |        789 | 1650.00 |
| Registration | June      |        6 |        123 | 325.00  |
| Registration | June      |        6 |        456 | 428.00  |
| Registration | June      |        6 |        789 | 165.00  |
| Maintenance  | June      |        6 |        123 | 1850.00 |
| Maintenance  | June      |        6 |        456 | 2509.00 |
| Maintenance  | June      |        6 |        789 | 1600.00 |
| Fuel         | June      |        6 |        123 | 1225.00 |
| Fuel         | June      |        6 |        456 | 1055.00 |
| Fuel         | June      |        6 |        789 | 275.00  |
+--------------+-----------+----------+------------+---------+
```

You could also use this to do an `INSERT` if need be.